# Specifying different thickness for each graded contours of Mandelbrot Set so that I can export it as .STL file.

Tags: complex, image3d, 3d-printing

I am using Mandelbrot Set function in Mathematica to get the Mandelbrot plot. I want to 3d print this model, so want to specify thickness for each contour and then convert into .STL file. Is this possible?

Comment: What Mathematica function are you using to create a Mandelbrot Set contour plot?  `ManderbrotPlot` produces a raster plot, according to its documentation.

Comment: Can you provide some type of example of what you wish the output to be?  In my experience the neat features of a M-Set are far too fine to be rendered with current 3D printers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach based on converting the image to LAB and using the L channel

```
baseData = ImageData[
   ColorConvert[
    MandelbrotSetPlot[Frame -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None],
    "LAB"
    ]
   ];

ListPlot3D[baseData[[;; , ;; , 1]], PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False]
```

[image]

This won't print well at all because of the tiny spikes. You can also smooth some of that out if you want a somewhat more printable version

```
ListPlot3D[
 BlockMap[
  Mean@*Flatten,
  Clip[baseData[[;; , ;; , 1]], {0.001, 1}, {1, 1}],
  {3, 2}
  ], PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Finally, if you are willing to figure out what `L` value each contour corresponds to, you can use `Map` to set things to that heigh

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
pts = ImageData[ColorNegate@Binarize@bild];
g = RegionPlot3D[
    pts[[Sequence @@ Round@{i, j}]] == 1, {i, 1, #1}, {j, 1, #2}, {z, 
     0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> False, Axes -> False, 
    Boxed -> False] & @@ Dimensions[pts]
pts = Cases[g, x_GraphicsComplex :> First@x, Infinity]
```

[image: extruded Mandelbrot plot]

This can be exported to STL via the built-in.

Modern alternatives are:

```
With[{h = 50},(*height*)
 RegionProduct[ImageMesh[bild], MeshRegion[{{0}, {h}}, Line[{1, 2}]]]]
```

and

```
ImageMesh[Image3D[ConstantArray[bild, 50]]]
```

h is here pixel.

Export["Test.stl", pts, {"STL", "BinaryFormat" -> False}]

This example might not be complete on `Import`.

Comment: OP wants to be able to specify a different thickness for each contour. This only provides a uniform thickness.